# Check if word in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp

I am planning to set up a simple function to see if words from a `wordlist` can be found in a Pandas DataFrame `common_words`. In case of a match, I would like to return the corresponding DataFrame entry, while the DF has the format `life balance 14, long term 9, upper management 9`, while always showing a word pair and its number of occurrence.

The code below is however currently only printing the search term from the `wordlist`, not the results that include the occurrence count. Where is my error in reasoning?

The relevant code section is:

```
    def wordcheck():
        wordlist = ["work balance", "good management", "work life"]
        for x in wordlist:
            if df[i].str.contains(x).any():
                print('Group 1:', x)
    wordcheck()
```

The full code is:

```
# Loading and normalising the input file
file = open("glassdoor_A.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)


# Datetime conversion
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# Adding of 'Quarter' column
df['Quarter'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('Q')


# Word frequency analysis
def get_top_n_bigram(corpus, n=None):
    vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2), stop_words='english').fit(corpus)
    bag_of_words = vec.transform(corpus)
    sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0)
    words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vec.vocabulary_.items()]
    words_freq =sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return words_freq[:n]


# Analysis loops through different qualitative sections, obtaining a dictionary
for i in ['Text_Pro','Text_Con','Text_Main']:
    common_words = get_top_n_bigram(df[i], 500)
    for word, freq in common_words:
        print(word, freq)


    # Check if word from list can be matched with DataFrame results
    def wordcheck():
        wordlist = ["work balance", "good management", "work life"]
        for x in wordlist:
            if df[i].str.contains(x).any():
                print('Group 1:', x)
    wordcheck()
```

Comment: what is `df` ? Can you show the inputs?

Comment: It's a Pandas dataframe. I have added the part of the code

Comment: Most of the code shown is extraneous. Reducing it to the minimal, simplest code that exhibits the problem will a) probably cause you to understand and fix the problem and b) provide us with something that we can help with.

Comment: I agree - plan was to show how the relevant variables are formed. Also, there has been a specific request to show inputs, which is why I have added these code sections. Hope that helps clarifying

Comment: Have carved out the relevant code section in an update.

Comment: Can you show an example of the value of `common_words`?

Comment: `common_words` shows key word pairs and the number of their occurrence, e.g.:  `life balance 14`, `long term 9`, `upper management 9`

Comment: Ok I have found a partial solution by working with a DataFrame approach. Have updated the code in the question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Try the `dict.get()` method:

```
# Check if word can be matched in dictionary
def wordcheck():
    wordlist = ["work balance", "management", "work balance"]
    for i in wordlist:
        if common_words.get(i):
            print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks for the good idea. It did not yield any output either unfortunately.